# How to calculate the sum of each day with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sum

I want to summarise each day of my table. The values in the original table are minutes, but these are way to exactly I only need the value of 24 hours.
The original table looks like this three columns and x rows:

```
Datum   Zeit    Rad
01.01.2017  00:01:00    0
01.01.2017  00:02:00    0
01.01.2017  00:03:00    0
01.01.2017  00:04:00    0
01.01.2017  00:05:00    0
01.01.2017  00:06:00    0
01.01.2017  00:07:00    0
01.01.2017  00:08:00    0
01.01.2017  00:09:00    0
01.01.2017  00:10:00    0
```

I changed the datetime with pandas to 2017-01-01 so that the table looks like:
2017-01-01      00:01:00     0

Is it even possible to count every Bike(Rad) on every day.

My idea is, sum all Bike(Rad) till the datetime changes to 02.01.2017 and then to 03.01.2017.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Tab = pd.read_csv('Komplett.csv', delimiter=';')

print(Tab.head())

#Tab.Rad = Tab.Rad.astype(int)
#Tab.Rad.astype(int)

#print(Tab.Rad.dtypes)

#print(Tab.Rad)

#print(Tab.Rad[0:1440])
#print(Tab[0:1439])

#print(len(Tab))

#sum = np.sum(Tab.Rad[0:1439])
#Date = Tab.Datum[1438]
#print(Date, sum)


Tab['Datum']  = pd.to_datetime(Tab.Datum)
print(Tab.head())


#Day=Tab[Tab.Datum=='2017-01-01']
#print(np.sum(Day.Rad))
```

New output:

```
        Datum      Zeit  Rad
0  01.01.2017  00:01:00    0
1  01.01.2017  00:02:00    0
2  01.01.2017  00:03:00    0
3  01.01.2017  00:04:00    0
4  01.01.2017  00:05:00    0
       Datum      Zeit  Rad
0 2017-01-01  00:01:00    0
1 2017-01-01  00:02:00    0
2 2017-01-01  00:03:00    0
3 2017-01-01  00:04:00    0
4 2017-01-01  00:05:00    0
```

Comment: I guess I am little confused as to what you are asking but does `df.groupby('Datum').size()` get close to what you are looking for

Comment: Hey Chris,thank you for your fast response. I change the size() to sum(), and it worked, but pandas got confused by the date. Its switch the 02.Januar (01.02) with the 01.February (02.01), and so on. Independently if i use the orginial date or the pd.to_datetime function. Do you have any ideas to avoid it ?

Comment: look at the [pd.to_datetime docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) you can specify the format of you date column so it will parse correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much, i wish you a nice christmas :)